# Ubuntu 13.10-desktop doesn't detect wi-fi adapter under vmware

Tags: wireless, 13.10, vmware

I'm new in Linux at all and I just installed Ubuntu on virtual machine. The problem is that there is no wi-fi network. On cable no problems but when I unplug lan cable there is no wi-fi.

So far i tryed to 'Software Update' but I don't see update for wifi driver or something.

What can be the problem? Can you point me what and where to check?

edit:

This happen also on real not virtual machine. Laptop is Dell Vustro 1500. Only wired network and no wireless?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VMware if I remember rightly has a bridged mode in its Network settings that allows you to emulate a physical network. Try enabling that. Sorry I can't go in to more detail than that but as long as your OS running VMware is connected to the Internet Ubuntu will be too.

EDIT:

"This happen also on real not virtual machine. Laptop is Dell Vustro 1500. Only wired network and no wireless?"

This suggests you are missing wireless drivers. You should be able to download these off of Dells website.

Comment: There is no driver on dell website for linux

Comment: What operating system is your virtual machine running in?

Comment: Well is not virtual any more.

Comment: Connect your computer up to the Internet via Ethernet and go to system settings --> software & updates --> Additional drivers and see if there is any there for your device. If that does not work see if this helps you: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/

Comment: Tryed both doesn't help :(